# Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Good, I ask your help in the following problem, I have a document php with a code that removes the cover of songs that estam an xml document site last fm, the problem is that I have the correct code only when there is no cover the following message "Fatal error: Call to a member function xpath () on a non-object in /home/vhosts/radiojevn.6te.net/lastfm-3.php on line 23" I've tried modifying the code but without success .

If anyone able to help me I'm grateful!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
 background-image: url(http://www.playtech.com.br/Imagens/produtos/indisponivel_vitrine.gif);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;

}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://radiojoven.6te.net/NowOnAir.xml');
if ($xml === false) 
    {
        echo("Url failed"); // do whatever you want to do
    }
$artist = urlencode($xml->Event->Song->Artist['name']);
$url = simplexml_load_file("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=$artist&api_key=50ac27433c63f7298064f434f4ef6d15");
$largeImage = $url->xpath('/lfm/artist/image[@size="mega"]')[0];
echo '<img src="'.$largeImage.'" ';  
?>width="100%" height="100%" />
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like simplexml_load_file has failed and $url is probably false, instead of an object. Do a `var_dump($url);` to confirm, then do a search for "simplexml_load_file errors" on this site for further debugging...

Comment: @rjdown I'll try to find out the errors, only when there no cover is that it gives me the error and you see this text, I just wanted to remove it, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is not valid xml file http://radiojoven.6te.net/NowOnAir.xml
If you just wanted remove error use

```
<?php
 $xml = @simplexml_load_file('http://radiojoven.6te.net/NowOnAir.xml');
if ($xml !== false) 
{
    $artist = urlencode($xml->Event->Song->Artist['name']);
    $url = simplexml_load_file("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=$artist&api_key=50ac27433c63f7298064f434f4ef6d15");
    $largeImage = $url->xpath('/lfm/artist/image[@size="mega"]')[0];
    echo '<img src="'.$largeImage.'" ';  
    ?>width="100%" height="100%" /><?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, it was just that we wanted!